# The correct way to set environment variables using options statement in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS is there a difference between these statements?

```
options set = varName "test";
options varName = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the SAS 9.4 Companion for Windows, the first method is the accepted syntax.

The second form produced an error in my test, and would be confused with the usual option=value syntax.